# sending fix string instead of quickfix.Message in quickfixj

Tags: fix-protocol, quickfixj

Is there anyway we can send out fix string messages directly without load it to the quickfix.Message first.

The reason we would like to do that sometimes there are some custom tags that will be gone missing after we parse the string to the object without having proper DataDictionary

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there just isn't a way to do this.

You **need** to have an accurate DataDictionary.  [Editing the DD is not difficult.](http://quickfixn.org/tutorial/custom-fields-groups-and-messages.html)

Often the hardest part is just getting the right info from your counterparty.  Sometimes you start with whatever you can get from them and then make adjustments based on what you see in reality.